# minimum edits -- question up the stack

Tags: discussion, edits

It seems that editing a question will push the question back on top of the "active" stack. Is there a minimum amount of editing required to push it on top, or will people be able to abuse the system by just adding a comma, a space, etc, to have their question always visible?

Comment: Edits have minimum change requirements, but in general, even minor edits are "activity". I don't see this as a particular problem, though.

Comment: Note that there's a record of every edit you make. That makes it pretty easy to see when you're gaming the system this way, and we don't regard this as acceptable behavior. I've had a few conversations with people about this, and they all stopped it right away.

Answer (score 1):

While there is a minimum edit size, it's pretty small, and it does always push the post back to the top of the list. However, there is already a partial safe-guard against abuse here. See [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

> How does a post become a Community Wiki post?
>
> There are several ways a question or answer can enter community wiki
>   mode, and most of these ways will occur automatically based on the
>   rules of the system.
>
> Posts enter community wiki mode when one of the following happens:
>
> - ...
> - The post has been edited ten (10) times by the original owner.
> - ...

And:

> Voting on a community wiki post (up or down) does not affect any
>   user's reputation.

So if you edit your post 10 times (not including a short grace period right after posting), it becomes Community Wiki and you no longer receive reputation. This is a disincentive for editing too much.

Comment: gd......................................................................